# FutureWarning: .loc or [] with missing label, suggests to use .reindex()

Tags: python, pandas

My input dataframe has `Date` in quarter format and `Rate`. There are missing quarter in `Date`. Now I am trying to compute the `Update` based on logic that if 3rd last quarter row is available then pick this Rate otherwise pick the last row Rate. My current code looks like below:

```
# Create dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, '2015Q3'], [2, '2015Q4'], 
                    [6, '2017Q1'], [7, '2017Q4'], 
                    [9, '2018Q1'], [3, '2018Q2'],
                    [5, '2018Q3'], [4, '2018Q4']],
                  columns=['Rate', 'Date'])
df1.index = pd.PeriodIndex(df1.Date, freq='Q')
df1.drop(columns='Date', inplace=True)

# This Code produces 'FutureWarning' message
df1['Update'] = np.where(np.in1d(df1.index - 3, df1.index.values),
                         df1.loc[df1.index - 3].Rate, df1.Rate.shift(1))
```

A complete warning message is as below:

```
FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

See the documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike
```

Link in warning: [deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike)

I understand that since there is arithmetic calculation on my `index` and some of the `index` value on calculation is not present which is causing this warning message and suggesting to use [pandas.DataFrame.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html). Although my intention is to access `Rate` only if `index` is available based on the `True` or `False` value from the condition in `np.where` but I guess numpy calculates for all and hence the missing `index.`

I tried by expanding the `Date` range, but it will have the same issue near the boundary. So, now my question is how to resolve this warning message. Any insights / thoughts / info / links would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in preparation for what `np.where` may or may not need, `df.loc[df.index - 3]` gets evaluated for all values of `df.index - 3`.  The warning message is a good one and suggests that you should use `df.reindex(df.index - 3)` instead.

```
df1['Update'] = np.where(np.in1d(df1.index - 3, df1.index.values),
                         df1.reindex(df1.index - 3).Rate, df1.Rate.shift(1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @piRSquared, warning is removed. From the examples shown in the link, it was not clear that it has to be used this way.